# How would I import an image to an Arduino and convert it to a binary bitstream?

Tags: image, arduino, led

I am working on a project to transmit data using an array of LEDs. However I'm having trouble importing an image to an Arduino. Once I have imported the image I would like to convert it into a binary form so I can transmit the data stream. Could anyone help me find a way to do this or any references?

Answer (score 0):

"Importing" is probably all you need to do, the classical approach is to use some tool like [`bin2c`](https://github.com/gwilymk/bin2c) to convert the raw binary file into C source code, which can then be compiled into the project.

This moves the problem to "how do I convert an image to raw binary", which is of course done by various image manipulation tools. Note that raw binary doesn't have a way of expressing its size, which you normally want to have available at runtime, so you need to figure out a way to add that. Perhaps hard-coding it is okay for your application, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your image to binary with [bin2c](https://github.com/gwilymk/bin2c) or [this](https://gist.github.com/suapapa/2935113), then use [PROGMEM](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/) to store the data and retrieve it.

Anyway, the image binary format will strongly depend on the format expected by your array of LEDs (is it B&W? RGB? What's the resolution?)